# ¿Cómo eliminar archivo PDF generado con itextsharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, itextsharp

Tengo una duda, necesito eliminar un archivo generado con itextsharp,dentro la misma instancia del método que lo construye. El problema es que me da un error que dice que el archivo esta siendo usado por otro proceso.

```
string nombre_documento = certificadoModel.Crear_Documento();

//valida creacion de certificado
if (nombre_documento != null){
     string correo = "algo@algo.com";
     email = correoModel.MensajeCorreo(correo, nombre_documento);
     //envia un correo con el documento adjunto
     server.Send(email);
     server.Dispose();
     System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\\Desarrollos\\Certificados\\ArchivosPDF\\"+nombre_documento }
```

El método que genera el documento está en una clase externa, luego de crear y escribir el documento, me he asegurado de cerrar tanto el documento como la escritura en el (doc.Close();, writer.Close();). Luego de instanciarlo, envío un correo adjuntando el archivo, luego de enviarlo cierro la instancia del servidor de correos, pero aún así no consigo eliminarlo.

Comment: Probablemente en tu método `Crear_Documento` se sigue referenciando el documento. Debes hacer `Dispose` de todos los objetos de clases que implementen `IDisposable`

Comment: dentro del método Crear_Documento, antes de finalizar la función tengo esto: //finaliza la escritura del documento
                doc.Close();
                writer.Close();

Comment: Una cosa es cerrar el stream, y otra usar Dispose. Trata de añadirlo donde sea necesario

Comment: he puesto el método .DIspose() en donde es posible acceder al archivo pero aun así no sale de la excepcion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He recibido ayuda en otro foro, la que comparto a continuación. Para adjuntar un archivo sin bloquearlo la clave esta en asignar un stream al attach del mail y no directamente el archivos indicando su ruta física.

En este caso se crea un método que ayudará en esta tarea, tomando la ruta del archivo y devolviendo el Stream.

Modifiqué el método que creaba el correo electrónico, dentro del cuál adjuntaba el PDF

```
public MailMessage MensajeCorreo(string archivo)
    {
        MailMessage mensaje = new MailMessage();
        mensaje.Subject = "DSI - Certificado";
        mensaje.To.Add(new MailAddress("correo@correo.cl"));
        mensaje.From = new MailAddress("correo@correo.cl", "Sistema de Certificados");
        mensaje.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:\\Desarrollos\\Certificados\\ArchivosPDF\\"+archivo));
        mensaje.Body = "Hola este es un mensaje de prueba";

        return mensaje;

    }//fin MensajeCorreo
```

Y utilizando lo que aparece en este Blog http://ltuttini.blogspot.cl/2012/08/mailmessageadjuntar-archivo-sin.html, modifiqué el método anterior, enviando no la ruta del archivo, sino el archivo en si:

```
public MailMessage MensajeCorreo(string archivo)
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("C:\\Desarrollos\\Certificados\\ArchivosPDF\\" + archivo))
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            memStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
            fileStream.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

            MailMessage mensaje = new MailMessage();
            mensaje.Subject = "DSI - Certificado";
            mensaje.To.Add(new MailAddress("correo@correo.cl"));
            mensaje.From = new MailAddress("correo@correo.cl", "Sistema de Certificados");
            mensaje.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memStream, Path.GetFileName(archivo), "application/pdf"));
            mensaje.Body = "Hola este es un mensaje de prueba";

            return mensaje;
        }

    }//fin MensajeCorreo
```

De esta manera puedo eliminar el documento como inicialmente lo propuse, y sin la necesidad de utilizar el Server.Dispose():

```
    string nombre_documento = certificadoModel.Crear_Documento();

//valida creacion de certificado
if (nombre_documento != null){
     string correo = "algo@algo.com";
     email = correoModel.MensajeCorreo(correo, nombre_documento);
     //envia un correo con el documento adjunto
     server.Send(email);
     System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\\Desarrollos\\Certificados\\ArchivosPDF\\"+nombre_documento 
}
```

Comment: bueno es que @Tuttini saaaaapbe :P

Comment: el mejor de los mejores na mas